# DFRS has gone mad. Copying old files back

Tags: windows, powershell, xcopy

**My Issue**
Our DFRs has gone mad and was having issues. It started copying back older versions of files from the destination to the source server.
Users have been updating files in the source server since last nights backup. 
I am not sure what has been copied back though.

**What I want to do** is check the timestamp of files located in \SourceServer\Folder1 (and sub folders) and \TargetServer\Folder1 (and sub folders) and copy the latest version of all files to a separate Folder (say \SourceServer\Folder2)
Then I can restore the other files from last nights backup.

I have seen a way to use Powershell Compare-Object but only using a -referenceObject and a -differenceObject

All help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use `robocopy` for that task. Run the following on SourceServer:

```
robocopy C:\path\to\Folder1 C:\path\to\Folder2 /e /copyall /dcopy:t /xj
robocopy \\TargetServer\Folder1 C:\path\to\Folder2 /e /copyall /dcopy:t /xj /xo
```

For general troubleshooting of DFS-R see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/11/01/common-dfsr-configuration-mistakes-and-oversights.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-dfsr-debug-logging-part-1-logging-levels-log-format-guid-s.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I didnt think of doing it in such a simplified manner. Using the /XO to exclude older files really helps.